# What diagram in Enterprise Architect matches Simulink models or DirectShow graphs most?

Tags: graph, directshow, diagram, simulink, enterprise-architect

Models in Simulink (Matlab) are consisted of interconnected "blocks". Edges on these models represent "wires", i.e. signal flow from block to block

[image]

DirectShow also based on graphs of interconnected nodes, called "filters". Wires represent merely the same.

[image]

How to draw similar diagrams in Enterprise Architect?

Comment: Looks similar to SysML to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SysML Block Definition Diagrams (BDD) with flow ports for the connection of the nodes needed in both DirectShow graphs and Simulink models.

Enterprise architect supports SysML in the Systems Engineering and Ultimate editions.